# E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript (Angular4 + e2e)

Tags: angular2, protractor

У меня проект на angular2 cli.
Когда я выполняю команду для тестирования:

> ng e2e

Я не изменяла файлы, сгенеренированные изначально, для тестирования:

```
      E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/@types/jasmine/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/@types/node/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/@types/q/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/@types/selenium-webdriver/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/blocking-proxy/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/events/events.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/events/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/protractor/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/q/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
File '/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/package.json' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. (6054)
    at getOutput (/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:300:15)
    at /home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:330:16
    at Object.compile (/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:489:17)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:382:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:385:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:93:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:92:18)
    at Jasmine.execute (/home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:197:8)
    at /home/NIX/alaeva/projects/angular-app/node_modules/protractor/built/frameworks/jasmine.js:132:15
[17:41:04] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Моя папка e2e содержит следующие файлы:

- app.e2e-spec.ts
- app.po.ts
- tsconfig.e2e.json

Мой tsconfig.e2e.json

```
    {
 "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
 "compilerOptions": {
   "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "target": "es6",
   "types":[
     "jasmine",
     "node"
   ],
   "typeRoots": [
     "../node_modules/@types"
   ]
 }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Спасибо, перевела.